# rails image hover - makes black bar on bottom

Tags: css

I am using rails and starting by creating my application layout with my logo at the top. The logo is a link to the homepage.

When i hover the image it creates a black bar along the bottom of it, it must be a default style or something but i cannot seem to find anywhere that is making it do this..

Has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks

also - to try to debug it i opened up the chrome debugger and watched the styles for both the link element and the image element, and nothing is changing between when i am hovering and not hovering.

Comment: are you using a css reset? something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: yeah i am using a css reset, and it is the one given in the answer on that question

Answer (score 0):

Just add the CSS line :

```
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working for me... is there any way to see all of the "hover" styles in a browser for an element?

Comment: @TroyCosentino in chrome inspector, in the styles window, there are 3 small buttons, the middle one allows you to simulate :hover on an element

Comment: @PeterVR great thank you this helped me figure it out. in scaffold.css.scss that was generated there was a a:hover that changed the background color to black.. not sure why that was an auto feature... but got it fixed so i am happy. Thanks!